Leaving a career job shortly after (6 to 18 months) for a phd
TL DR; Accepted a job and a few months in I am considering applying for a PhD because it's the best move in my career as I like that path plus I am from a really poor country and I am currently underpaid.
Edit: Engineering
Hello, I need some help navigating the situation.

Switched careers so I am a bit behind, but with double degree, almost 30 yo
Living in a poor country with little opportunities
I have really good letters of recommendation and a profile that will be well-valued abroad

After finishing my studies abroad I decided to take an academic break instead of going to a PhD, because if I do so I won't be able to work in my country, and wanted to try it out before giving it up. I planned to get a job asap and after a year or year and a half re-evaluate.
Ended up spending 9 months unemployed and finally got a job. During the interview, I still was convinced to try out things here, but the offer took a long time and the job started 3 months later. The position is not in my preferred field, some transferable skills are useful but the pay is abysmal, to the point being frugal allows me to save 100 USD per month.
My situation right now is that I realize I have no future here, my preferred field is non-existent, the economic situation might even get worse, and by my age, I am afraid I won't be able to leave my country. Staying will make me dependent on a narrow and underpaid job market with no appealing projects.
I miss research and want to do the PhD in Europe now, I know I will work hard if I get into the right position. So I am starting to consider applying to positions that might get me there after being 6 months into the job, but nothing is certain.
I want to know your take on the situation. To be honest I feel really guilty about leaving a job soon. Do I wait a year or two? If I do apply for PhD how long should I wait until I put the job in the cv? Now 3 months in? 6? If they ask do I tell them in short I see no opportunities where I am?

just as a side note: take into account that a PhD application can take a while and you have no guarantee whether you get accepted at your first choice/attempt. So even if you start applying now, you might still be in the current job for quite a while. And if you need moral justification: you could have started applying way before your current job and just taken it to pay the bills until a phd application finally gets you a spot. Life is a series of opportunities that cannot be perfectly planned ahead of time.

@FrankHopkins yeah specially being the case I am targeting MSCA positions which are weirder and better paid. I might never get the position after all


... I feel really guilty about leaving a job soon.

No need. They wouldn't feel guilty to fire you if it becomes necessary. Not sure if you have a probation time, but it's not unusual that things don't work out early in the game.

Do I wait a year or two?

Wait for what? You are not getting any younger and what you are doing won't help your Ph.D. application. In fact it might take you a while to line up a Ph.D. and sort out Visa/Immigration issues, so the earlier you start the better.

If I do apply for PhD how long should I wait until I put the job in the cv?

Your CV should accurately represent your work history. If you are currently working there you should list it with the correct starting date.

If they ask do I tell them in short I see no opportunities where I am?

There is no need to tell them anything but there is also no harm in having an open discussion around it, if you feel it would helpful either to you or to them.
A word of caution: If you start a Ph.D. at this point you are  likely locking yourself into an academic career. Going back into industry after a late Ph.D. will be quite difficult. Make sure that this is what you want and that you are aware of the risks.

I see thanks.. about being lock in, this would be Europe and a really high regard PhD with industrial connections so I guess ageism is not going to be that much an issue

Depending on the field, I wouldn't see a particular problem switching from academia to industry - at least if OP manages to stay in Europe, they already described that the job market in their home country currently is not in the best shape so in that case just getting a decent job might be hard either way.. do you have any data around that assumption? OP would be 34/35ish with their PhD - which imho isn't any issue. I've seen people switch at that age without problem and would argue that the PhD might actually give them an edge on the international market.

@FrankHopkins I did an internship at an European country and talked about my future if I chose a phd at that moment.. he said me that i would have no issues going into industry. Even more he said it was more common than staying in academia where positions are limited

Your mileage my vary. I got my Ph.D. in Germany and just barely managed to make the jump to industry since I had build a really good network . Obviously that depends on the specific field but at 35 you will be competing against candidates with 5-10 years of actual hands on  job experience. Once you are 5+ years in the real world, no one cares about your academic credentials anymore and most people I work with have no idea that I am a "Doktor" (nor would they care).

@Hilmar applied photonics/ optics. Not expecting to earn as much as a 30 yo but as much as someone with just the phd. Even then would be wide more than what I can achieve after a whole career in my country.

@Hilmar even different experiences / opinions and job contexts aside, especially in OP's case the PhD from Europe would be pitted against a work experience from whereever OP works in a job that doesn't seem too much in the area they want to work in and from a job market that seems not too promising - and potentially holds somewhat lower value in the eyes of European companies (and might come with Visa issues/concerns). Plus a PhD can open higher level job opportunities (more rare but more likely to invest the visa effort). Anyhow, I'd just recommend to relax the wording a bit as improvement.

but your choice of course^^

@FrankHopkins yeah your visa analysis is exactly what I think. What do you mean about the wording? Sorry but I did not get that

@RandomEngineer that was directed at Hilmar, imho the hint at "locking oneself in an academic path" is somewhat valid as a general hint especially if we take this in the spirit of this page as a general answer (not just for your specific case), but as it is currently written it just sounds quite strong and the answer could from my perspective be improved by relaxing that part a bit.

@FrankHopkins ah I see. I understand that for a normal county working would be better for getting an economic improvement and a PhD would be economically unwise. Pitifully here I am ironically more locked and getting experience in my current position will only allow me to work for this employer forever.... That said we need to keep in mind I really like research so it's not just an scape

Going back for advanced study is one of the better reasons for leaving a job.
On the other hand: Some employers will help pay tuition if you are doing a part-time degree while working full time. Check what programs your current employer may offer along those lines.
(Mine would reimburse tuition of career-relevant classes from reputable institutions if we passed with a B or better, and would sometimes allow a term or two off from work with promise of a job when you returned if you were already halfway or more toward getting the degree. The more generous programs were, of course, harder to qualify for.)

This would be in another continent so no chance to keep the job. I would need to resign. That said in Europe you get paid to do the PhD and the programs I am thinking about are paying three times my current gross salary .. after taxes and cost of living I would be living much better and saving x3 to X5 times per month. Also the duration is 3 years

Sounds like a perfectly reasonable and defensible decision.
